# Security Issues when mounting WebDAV on windows

Tags: windows-7, security, webdav

When ever I try to access files/folders in my WebDAV that I have set up, It throws an error saying that My internet security settings suggest this file may be harmful. Where can I change this setting? For an example I have moved into a nearly empty folder and tried to move Archive.bat into New Folder (dragged archive into newfolder to be specific) and I get the screenshots below. [image]
Any suggestions on ways to help correct the security issue?

What I have tried: 
(1) I went to `Control Panel -> Internet Options` and added the domain name to my trusted sites, this seemed to have no effect.